ESP32: Powering on/off a MicroSD card via GPIO using a MOSFET
I want to power on or off a MicroSD card on my PCB via a GPIO of my ESP32. This allows me to restart it without removing the main power supply.
Switching on the low side (ground) might not be a good idea, so I used a P-Channel instead of a N-Channel MOSFET.
However, using a P-Channel MOSFET would cause the power being on while the ESP32 is booting or offline for whatever reason because the output GPIO would be LOW. I only want the MicroSD card being powered on if I explicitly set the GPIO to high.
So, my idea was to use a P-Channel MOSFET together with a NPN transistor:

I also created a Falstad Circuit Simulation:

My questions are:

Is this approach correct?
Is there better and simpler approach?


There is no such thing as a "PNP MOSFET" or an "NPN MOSFET"; pnp and npn are types of BJT, not types of MOSFET.

You're right of course. I updated the text and Simulation accordingly.


For switching the power itself, yes. But for data, not really. When card is unpowered, the data lines are pulled to supply, possibly powering the card via protection diode.

Maybe, but if your assumption is correct that ESP IO pins are low outputs at boot, then no. My assumption would be that IO pins are inputs that float. The ESP does have many strap pins that do pull weakly high or low before user code sets the pin mode and state.



Thanks, I need to connect the pull-ups to the MOSFET drain as well.
